# Server error in application in '/' Application,No such host is known

Tags: c#, asp.net, nslookup

```
 string[] computer_name = System.Net.Dns.GetHostEntry(Request.ServerVariables["remote_addr"]).HostName.Split(new Char[] { '.' });
```

`
1.I have this an error coming from another user on this line while saving an image in the DB through the application that it cannot find their Host,but it works fine by my side and i can save successfully.
2.I know that from this error,clearly that the dns entry for the user's address might not be in the server DNS catalog and the server might have not found the entry via recursive lookup.
My Question is,how do you check my ipadress entry and the users entry in the server DNS Catalog?using nslookup maybe.

`

Comment: How do you know the other user has a DNS entry?

Comment: Is your user on the same domain (intranet) as you?  If not, you are unlikely to get a successful DNS lookup.

Comment: All the other users that can use the application successfully  are on the same domain with me.